# PHP and Shortcode Combination

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

On my website i would like to display the social locker wordpress plugin around a custom field.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[sociallocker]'.$to_lock.'[/sociallocker]');?>
```

Here is my custom field

```
<?php the_field('link'); ?>
```

Social locker requires a open and close shortcode:

```
[sociallocker id="16619"]
[/sociallocker]
```

The following does not work correctly:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[sociallocker id="16619"]'); ?>
<?php the_field('link'); ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[/sociallocker]'); ?>
```

Comment: Could you write then what does this code display on your HTML page? And have you tried to use `<?= get_field ('link'); ?>` instead of `<?php the_field('link'); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

The function `do_shortcode` accept a single shortcode, you can't pass parts of the shortcode (open tag, content, closing tag) separately.

In case there is opening and closing shortcode, you should call it like following.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[s_tag]' . $content . '[/s_tag]' ); ?>
```

So, you've to update your following lines to

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[sociallocker id="16619"]'); ?>
<?php the_field('link'); ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode('[/sociallocker]'); ?>
```

With a single `do_shortcode` call.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[sociallocker id="16619"]' . get_field('link') . '[/sociallocker]'); ?>
```

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/